# Time returns 0 in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, time, binary-search-tree

I want to measure time it takes to search for x, problem is that its always 0.
I tried using different methods of calculating time with no luck.
If I calculate insertion then it works properly, so why is that it doesn't work in other case?

Functions work correctly because they are taken from site that explain BST, my task is to calculate and analyse time taken to complete functions.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node *newNode(int item)
{
    struct node *temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return newNode(key);

    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
}

struct node * minValueNode(struct node* node)
{
    struct node* current = node;


    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct node* search(struct node* root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL || root->key == key)
        return root;

    if (root->key < key)
        return search(root->right, key);


    return search(root->left, key);
}


struct node* deleteNode(struct node* root, int key)
{ 
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);
    else
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);
        root->key = temp->key;
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->key);
    }
return root;
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    clock_t start;
    struct node *root = NULL;

    for(int i=0; i<400000; i++)
    {
        root = insert(root,((rand()*rand())%20000));
    }

    double duration;

    start = std::clock();
    root = search(root, 19999);
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "Time: " << duration << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't compile--it has errors. Please fix.

Comment: I was sure this is C until I saw `std::clock`.

Comment: Should work now

Comment: You may want to use 1E06 data items or run your BST 1E06 iterations and use the average.  Most computers can execute thousands of instructions in 1 second.  The *clock* may not be accurate enough or detailed enough to measure one insertion into the tree.  Search the internet for "c++ benchmarking".

Comment: BTW, you only need `struct node` when setting up the structure; otherwise `node` is a type similar to `int, double` and `char`.

Comment: Also, prefer to use `new` instead of `malloc`.  The `malloc` function does not call the `struct` or `class` constructors.  Remember to use `delete` to return the deleted or unused data.  See also `std::shared_ptr`, which handles deletion for you.

Comment: Your tree allows insertion of duplicate keys.  When searching, do you choose the first key that matches, the 2nd?  The third?  I was taught that Binary Search Trees should not contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

**Your `insert` function does not return anything if the parameter `node` is not `NULL`.** This is Undefined Behaviour, and can result in literally anything, including [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Seeing that no segfault occurs, it would seem that compiler gracefully assigns `NULL` to the pointer `root` in main, which means your tree has at most two elements (and there are many, many such trees lost in memory). Searching for element in two element tree certainly can take 0 seconds. But that's just random guessing - it's UB, it can be everything.

---

You should enable compiler warnings (for `gcc` that would be for example flags `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`, preferably with `-Werror` to turn all warning into errors). Such issue would be very easy to find with compiler warnings.